# Email When Scheduled Job Fails

Tags: error, scheduled-job

When any scheduled job fails or throws an error is there a way to have it send out an email to me? I was thinking drupal rules but wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of failure happens this might help: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-error-report-handler

It will email you for more than just jobs but maybe you'd want that too.